# Изменение градиента colorbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

как изменить цветовую схему colorbar?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sc = ax.scatter([1, 2], [1, 2], c=[1, 3])
ax.set_ylabel('YLabel', loc='top')
ax.set_xlabel('XLabel', loc='left')
cbar = fig.colorbar(sc)
cbar.set_label("ZLabel", loc='top')

plt.show()
```

[image: Результат кода]

А хочется так:

[image: Желаемый результат]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так, банально cmap='jet')

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sc = ax.scatter([1, 2], [1, 2], c=[1, 3], cmap='jet')
ax.set_ylabel('YLabel', loc='top')
ax.set_xlabel('XLabel', loc='left')

cbar = fig.colorbar(sc)
cbar.set_label("ZLabel", loc='top')

plt.show()
```